# How to generate "client_secret.json" for Google API with offline access?

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, service-accounts, google-developers-console

I am trying to authenticate to Google API in a backend service using a [service account](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/oauth/service-accounts). It will not have a UI at all.

I have generated *private keys* in JSON format from Google Developer Console, using a `Service Account` but there is no field named "client_secret" in it.

I found this example on [GitHub](https://github.com/Seb69/Web-application-Spring-Boot-/blob/651f0cb6eb556742e76d837dec0808ba8e13af47/src/main/resources/googleapis/client_secret.json), and its structure should be correctly parsed by [`GoogleClientSecrets`](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-api-client/latest/com/google/api/client/googleapis/auth/oauth2/GoogleClientSecrets.html) class.

What are the steps to generate the correct `client_secret.json` as in the GitHub example?

Comment: Service Accounts do not have a client_secret key. You are confusing a service account and an OAuth user account.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I need to do this again after a long time, and I am documenting the steps as of May 2022.

---

- Login to Google Cloud Console
- Go to API Service -> Credentials
- Click "+ Create Credentials", ans select Service Account

  - Fill in service account name, it will create a default account id
  - Click "Create and Continue"
  - In the role selection screen, I selected owner as this was my personal project. If your service will be accessed by external parties, consider giving only required permissions
  - Click Continue
  - I did not select any user/admin role on screen 3. Click Done.
- You will be back on Credentials screen. Click the Service account Email you just created.

  - You should be on the Details tab. Click on the KEYS tab.
  - Click "Add Key" dropdown, and click "Create New Key".
  - Select JSON key type (default), and click create.
  - This should download a JSON file to you.

You can then use the credential to access Google services. For example, in my case I access YouTube service with the following code ( `clientSecretsStream` is the `InputStream` of that credentials JSON file):

```java
public static YouTube initializeYouTube(InputStream clientSecretsStream, String appName) throws IOException {
    final HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
    final JsonFactory jsonFactory = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

    GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.fromStream(clientSecretsStream)
            .createScoped(Collections.singleton(YouTubeScopes.YOUTUBE_READONLY));

    return new YouTube.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, credential)
            .setApplicationName(appName)
            .build();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you dont have a client secret then you have generated the wrong type of credentials.

To create a client_secret.json file. You go to [Google developer console](https://console.developers.google.com/).

1. Create a project
2. Go to the credentials tab on the left
3. click the button on the top of this page called "create credentials"
4. select "service account" in the drop down and fill in the required information.

You will then be promoted to download your client_secret.json file.

If you intend to use any of the google apis be sure to go to library on the left and enable the APIs you will be using.

Comment: After Step 4, I don't get prompted - I have to click on service account, then click "add Keys" -> "Create New Key". In this key file I do not see any "client_secret"